# Error Converting varchar to date in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

With this statement I can execute it fine:

```
SELECT sum(Amount) As '350' FROM Withdrawal 
WHERE WholeSellerId = 'Someone' AND DateAdded = '02-04-2016' And ProductId = '1'
```

But when I place it in a Stored Procedure like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetWithJR]
@WholeSellerId varchar(50),
@ProductId varchar(30),
@StartDate date
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT sum(Amount) As '350' FROM Withdrawal 
WHERE WholeSellerId = @WholeSellerId AND DateAdded = Cast(@StartDate as date) And ProductId = @ProductId
END
```

and execute it as so:

```
exec [dbo].[GetWithJR] 'Someone', '02-04-2016', '1'
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure GetWithJR, Line 0
Error converting data type varchar to date.
```

I tried using `Convert(date, @StartDate, 110)` and

```
Cast(@StartDate as date)
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The order of parameters in your call to the SP is incorrect. It should be: `exec [dbo].[GetWithJR] 'Someone', '1', '02-04-2016'`

Comment: Man.. I must be tired!.. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `@StartDate date` You declare @StartDate is a date type. Try to declare in varchar.

Comment: Be smart, if you insist on passing dates as varchars (you should use the `DATE` type instead), pass them as `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYY-MM-DD`. Those formats are locale neutral.

Comment: Thanks TT. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Is that February 4th or April 2nd? this string representation is ambiguous and should be avoided anywhere other then the UI. Take TT's advice and go with ISO formats.